# Why do I get "404 site not found" on products of copied project

Tags: magento-1.8

I created a copy of my project for developement.
Everything works, but I get `site not found` if I click on any product. I tried all different categories.

I already compared the category, article and even url rewrite of the working live environment with my copy. Everything is exactly the same, so it should work.

Caching is disabled. I even reindexed everything and deleted the cache even though it is deactivated, to get sure.

**What I've tried:**

---

- I went to "*System -> Configuration -> General -> Web*" and deactivated web server rewrite.
- Added "index.php" to my url e.g. *http://www.example.com/index.php/myproduct.html* instead of *http://www.example.com/myproduct.html*, but it did not helped at all.
- Called the product directly "*http://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/1787*"

---

I also checked the Rewrites in FIREGENTO, this is what I get:

[image]

What else can I try?

Comment: Is there a .htaccess-file in the base directory? Become all other routes rendered properly?

Comment: Yes, there is an .htaccess, it is a complete 1:1 copy of a working test environment. Every other route works as far as I know, but products are not showing.

Comment: @SaschaMichalski, I have to correct my selve, some other links in the nav are also not working correctly, they render "There are no items to choose from." All footer links work though.

Comment: Sounds like a missing or misconfigured .htaccess file

Comment: No, I think the database has a problem, since the project is as I said an 1:1 copy of the working environment. But I always had problem with importing the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. I had to export all the products from the source project via backend:

> (*SYSTEM -> Import/Export -> Export*)

[image: enter code here]

I did not skipped any Attributes and just clicked on the send button at the bottom right. This generated a .csv file.

Then I had to import the .csv file in the target backend:

> (*SYSTEM -> Import/Export -> Import*)

**Important:**

> **Do not forget to reindex everything at the end!**

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by following ways

1. "System -> Configuration -> General -> Web" and activated web server rewrite
2. Change mod_rewrite  in .htaccess file

   ```
   ############################################
      ## enable rewrites

       Options +FollowSymLinks
       RewriteEngine on

   ############################################
   ## you can put here your magento root folder
   ## path relative to web root

   ##RewriteBase /{{projectname}}/

   ############################################
   ## workaround for HTTP authorization
   ## in CGI environment

       RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

   ############################################
   ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

   ############################################
   ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   ############################################
   ## rewrite everything else to index.php

       RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Try to reindex   ***Catalog URL Rewrites*** && ***Category Products***

Facing from backend, try this.

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall {{This cmd reindexing all the data}}
```

Comment: First of, thanks for your answer. Does the php command execute only on the current folder or does it affect the whole server? Web server rewrite was already activated from the start, and the problem was there, I only deactivated it afterwards.

Comment: activated web server rewrite-- means you want to remove index.php file from your URL.
Above configuration is indicate that rewrite is not active on your server.
Basically in shared server rewrite mode is not active.
Need to use above configuration.

Comment: The project which I have copied is on the same shared server as the original, so It must work because It is an 1:1 copy of that project. I tried your configuration neverteless and it makes no difference at all.